# WordPress blog finding related PHP

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to edit a WordPress site. When I try to edit the `x.com/blog/` page nothing happens.

I am trying to find out which PHP files are related to set up the blog page, but I do not know how.

If I can find the right files I can edit those. So how can I edit the /blog page in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Open Admin Dashboard and edit page blog page and check which template is currently using for that page.Then go to "/wp-content/themes/[your-theme-name]/" and find that template.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Alternative you can check if x.com/blog/ is coming from archive page which is custom post type page. You can find it via go to "/wp-content/themes/[your-theme-name]/archive-blog.php"

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/wp-content/themes/[your-theme-name]/`. All files which are responsible for rendering the output can be found there.

Most likely index.php, home.php, front-page.php or page.php are responsible. The exact responsibility depends on the structure of the used theme.

Simple drop a

```
echo "This file is used currently.";
```

into the top of those themes and check if this appears in the source code if you are reloading the page.

Also make sure that any caching plugins are temporarily deactivated.

The basics on how WordPress themes are made and which template part is called can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development